# Rating outlet for an app

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, xcode4

just a quick question.. Could you suggest me an option how to design and implement a rating field. I saw on the internet that there are couple of options such as Textfield with Number formatter, radio group, comboBox which I could use. Please et me know, which is for suitable and how to implement it. Also, when I selected View->Utilities- > show objects Library in Xcode 4 it just shows the objects and not the objects library which I saw on the internet can u please guide me for that too

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of is to just use a text field and set the text to some number of unicode 2605 characters.